# Remove element from collection using IEnumerator in C#

Tags: c#

I need to remove an element from a list<> in C#. From the previous answers provided, it seems that one has to loop backwards through the collection to achieve this. But, I have an IEnumerator to iterate through elements of the list.
The code is as follows:

```
        IEnumerator<Solution> iterator = solutionsList_.GetEnumerator();
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {

            Solution element = iterator.Current;
            int flag = dominance_.Compare(solution, element);
            if (flag == -1) { // The Individual to insert dominates other
                // individuals in the archive
                iterator.Remove();} // Delete it from the archive
```

It would be very helpful if I could get some way of removing the element from the list<> along with using the enumerator.

Comment: What is `solutionsList_` is that list of `Solution`

Comment: Yes solutionsList_ is of type List<Solution>

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a `List<T>`, then there's no reason to explicitly grab the enumerator. You can just use a regular loop, and go backwards - and you'll be able to remove elements without any issue, here is a code sample:

```
var solutionsList_ = new List<int>();
for (var i = solutionsList_.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var element = solutionsList_[i];
    //if (Some logic)
    {
        solutionsList_.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IEnumerable's can only been enumerated, you cannot add/remove an item from it.

You can use an ICollection to add/remove items, you can try casting your IEnumerable to an ICollection as List implements ICollection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think You are complicating the scenario. You can Directly apply [LINQ extension methods](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq) over `List`. So You can simply use the following code to remove the Items from the List:

```
List<Solution> solutionsList_ = new List<Solution>() { };
// Populate the list here
var itemsToRemove = solutionsList_.Where(x => dominance_.Compare(solution, x) == -1);
foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
{
    solutionsList_.Remove(item);
}
```